# $stmt->get_result() works for SELECT on a MYSQL table but not on a view

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

my first question so please feel free to keep me right.

When I use $stmt->get_result() with a SELECT query on a **table** in my MYSQL database, I get a result set as expected.

If I run exactly the same code on a MYSQL **view**, the get_result() returns false. This happens even if the view constitutes a simple "SELECT *" from the table in question.

In terms of code, this will return a result set:

```
$q =  "SELECT * FROM table_name";
if ($stmt = $con->prepare($q)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($res = $stmt->get_result()) {
        echo "success";
    }     
    else
    {
        echo "fail";
        var_dump($res);
    }  
    $stmt->close();    
}
```

This will return **false** in the var_dump:

```
$q =  "SELECT * FROM view_name";
if ($stmt = $con->prepare($q)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($res = $stmt->get_result()) {
        echo "success";
    }     
    else
    {
        echo "fail";
        var_dump($res);
    }  
    $stmt->close();    
}
```

Many thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: you have whatever problem with your second query irrelevant to get_result

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. The second query (on the view) works fine and returns a result set if I execute it via MySQLWorkbench

Comment: ps .. after enabling the mysqli_report errors I see the error:  'Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared' - I will investigate on that basis, thanks again.